# how to delete the specified row from html table and also in mysql table using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently displaying the data using a html table in `php` from `mysql` database, and i also i am allowing the user to delete only their own data from the table,my problem is how to match the delete button with the respected row,when user clicks the delete buttons only the specified row should be deleted, but it deletes all the records which is connected to the user in the database, please help me how to do this, PS i am a learner and new to `php`

UPDATED CODE GOES HERE

```
   <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>View cart-d2dn</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
include('header.php'); ?>
<h1>View Cart</h1>

<table border='1'>
         <tr>
         <th> VIN </th>
         <th> Vehicle Description </th>
         <th> Price </th>
         </tr>
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$sql = "SELECT vin,description,price FROM products where user_id='".$_SESSION['use_i']."' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$uq=mysql_query("select * from td_user where user_id='".$_SESSION['use_i']."' ");
$u_row=mysql_fetch_array($uq);
if(isset($_REQUEST['delete']))
{
$sql_s =" DELETE FROM `products` WHERE user_id='".$u_row['user_id']."' AND vin='".$_REQUEST['vin']."' " ;
$result_s = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_s) ;
if($result_s == true)
{
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Deleted successfully")';
echo '</script>';
}
else
{
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Error in deletion")';
echo '</script>';
}
}
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$row['vin'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['description'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['price'].' </td>
            <td>  <form method="post"> <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
 <input type="hidden" name="vin" value="'.$row['vin'].'">
 </form></td>
        </tr>';

    }   
}
else
{
echo "Your cart is empty!";
}
?>        
<?php
echo '</table>';
?>
<form><input type="button" value="Go back" onClick="window.location.href='automobile_list.php'">
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="window.location.href='mail.php'">
</form>

<?php

mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<?php

include('footer.php');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: give each row a id, on delete delete row with mysql row

Comment: @MurtazaHussain : can you please tell me briefly on how to give a row a id, so that i will try to understand...sorry if am wrong

Comment: `session_start();` should always be on top of the page, even above html tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do same only if your MySQL table have primary/unique key OR each row is different...

If `VIN` is unique then Let me show where you need to change. You need to SEND the unique key with delete request to detect which row selected to be deleted. Change the delete button code to:

```
 <form method="post"> <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
      <input type="hidden" name="vin" value="'.$row['vin'].'">
 </form>
```

And in code of deleting row:

```
  if(isset($_REQUEST['delete']))
  {
    $sql_s =" DELETE FROM `products` WHERE user_id='".$_SESSION['use_i']."' AND vin='".$_REQUEST['vin']."' ";
  }
```

ALSO Delete the mysql code you are using to retrieve user ID (which is just before the code written above). [AND put this delete-code before displaying table(before selecting from product table-look at comments for more info :p )]

---

If `vin` is not the primary key then add primary in table by following mathed:

In mysql workbench: right click -> Alter table -> add column `ID` as `INT` and check the `PK` (primary key), `AI` (auto increment) -> apply -> finish.

Now use `ID` in place of `VIN`

---

As you said you are new to PHP. Then let me give a suggestion:

Use `$_POST` in place of `$_REQUEST` coz POST var contains data which sent by POST method only BUT `REQUEST` contains both POST & GET data... so anybody can delete via just typing in URL as `?delete=delete&vin=3`

BTW, its not the issue here, but will help you in future.

Comment: yes, vin and user id both are primary key..that is am using it as composite key in database...

Comment: @vivek: Good you can use this solution in that case. :) | I have given a suggestion also if you need.

Comment: Rajuput : Sorry for the disturbance,after pressing two times only it performs the delete operation.

Comment: @vivek it deletes in the first time, but your delete-php code is below the table(in which u are displaying records). That's why clicking-delete again reloads the page and you see actual table.... | **The solution is to put the PHP-deleting code before displaying table.** in you case JUST AFTER `if (!$conn) { die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); }`  | In PHP, php-code should be on top unless it needed to be at different place. [thanks for accepting answer, you can also use vote up if it is useful.]

Comment: thank you friend, i will try by putting the code above the table [i tried to use the vote up for your answer but i don't have 15 rep to use vote up, so only i accepted it as answer]

Comment: i pasted the code above the table, but now also i want to press the delete button twice to delete,can u please help me.

Comment: @vivek: ohhh I didn't know about that restriction... :P  | In that case I need to look at your code... Coz if you DELETE before SELECT from `product` table then it should not have deleted row in result. So how can it show deleted row and you need to press delete again to refresh. Its only possible if you are deleting after selecting from table. | Also tell me what happen when you press 'delete' once and then REFRESH button or F5...

Comment: if i press delete once and after that i press F5, then it deletes automatically.

Comment: @vivek: then I m sure your delete code is AFTER the select query... `if(isset($_REQUEST['delete'])){ $sql_s =" DELETE FROM products WHERE user_id='".$_SESSION['use_i']."' AND vin='".$_REQUEST['vin']."' ";` **`if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql_s)) { .... } else { ....  }  }`** code should be **BEFORE** `$sql = "SELECT vin,description,price FROM products where user_id='".$_SESSION['use_i']."' "; $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);`

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<tr id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >
                <td>'.$row['vin'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['description'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['price'].' </td>
                <td> <form method="post"> <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"></form> </td>
            </tr>';
            $vinrow =$row['vin'] ;
        }

    }
```

Comment: your query returning id ?

Comment: yes,i have unique id in database but i dont want to display it to user, and moreover VIN is also a unique no. like id